# How do I control jboss to start logging post application startup

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss6.x

We would like to trace all activity on `org.hibernate.type` category post application startup, since we would like to avoid all trace logs during application startup time (as it takes a long time).

Note: Currently `jboss6/server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml` contains a `TRACE` for `org.hibernate.type` category.

Is it possible to enable this post startup in a programmatic fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Write a POJO to check the status of JBoss server - whether it's started or not. You can tap into MBean: **jboss.system:type=Server** and inspect boolean property **Started**. If it's started, dynamically change the loggin level for Hibernate using something like this:

```
Logger hibernate = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(<logger name>);
hibernate.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
```

Now you can bundle this POJO with your application archive and schedule it as a quartz job to trigger after a minute or so.  When the POJO has done it's job, cancel its subsequent scheduling.

If you don't want to schedule it as a quartz job, you could deploy this a separate artifact under **deploy.last** folder and let it change the logging level right away without checking the JBoss server status.